# textbox not hiding with checkbox click (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, textbox

I have a textbox which I would like to appear on a checkbox click and disappear if the checkbox is unselected, however my code currently shows the textbox when the page loads, but once you select and then unselect the checkbox it disappears as its supposed to. Any ideas?

Javascript:

```js
function TMDFunction() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("tmd_checkbox");
  // Get the output text
  var text = document.getElementById("test");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    text.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    text.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="product" name="targetedmobiledisplay" value="0.08" id="tmd_checkbox" onclick="TMDFunction()">
Targeted Mobile Display
<br> 
Test: <input id="test" type="text" value="0.00" data-total="0" />
```

Comment: just add simple CSS to the textbox to set it to display none... `#test{display:none}` OR call `TMDFunction()` onload of your page

Comment: Side note; `text.style.display = (checkBox.checked ? 'block' : 'none');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, easy, add the style that you want as default, for example, you want to be `display: none`, so it is inserted on the HTML.

```js
function TMDFunction() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("tmd_checkbox");
  // Get the output text
  var text = document.getElementById("test");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    text.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    text.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="product" name="targetedmobiledisplay" value="0.08" id="tmd_checkbox" onclick="TMDFunction()"> Targeted Mobile Display
<br> 
Test: 
<input id="test" type="text" value="0.00" data-total="0" style="display:none;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`TMDFunction()` only runs when the checkbox is clicked. Initially when the page loads, the function is  not being called.

You can try hiding the textbox when the page loads with `document.ready`.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var text = document.getElementById("test");
  test.style.display = 'none';
});
```

This function will hide the textbox once the page loads.

Comment: how would I hide the text beside it? Should I add to a label and place inside the function?

Comment: Wrap the text and the textbox inside a `<div>` and hide it when the page loads